# Unable to post data to the remote server due to incompatible OpenSSL versions between remote server and local work-station

Tags: php, ssl, web, https, openssl

I am in a situation that I need to find another solution to post the data via PHP curl to the remote server without updating the current PHP version 5.4.9 to 7 or higher just to solve the OpenSSL incompatibilities.

**Local Server**

- Operation System: Windows 7, 32 bit architecture
- PHP version: 5.4.9
- OpenSSL Version: 0.9.8x

**Remote Server(https)**

- PHP version: 7.2.27
- OpenSSL version: 1.0.2k

**Here's my PHP code**

```
<?php

$url = "https://****/api/daily/sales";
$headers = array(
    'AUTH-TOKEN: *****',
    'CONTENT-TYPE: application/json'
);

$items = array(
    'customer_no'=>'001',
    'customer_name'=>'John Smith',
    'customer_address'=>'Bohol Philippines',
    'customer_province'=>'Bohol',
    'customer_city'=>'Tagbilaran',
    'salesman_no'=>'001',
    'salesman_name'=>'Salesman A',
    'salesman_mobile_no'=>'0912345678',
    'supervisor_id'=>'001',
    'supervisor_name'=>'Supervisor A',
    'item_no'=>'001',
    'item_description'=>'Detergent',
    'qty'=>2,
    'price'=>5,
    'uom'=>'pcs',
    'sales_value'=>'10',
    'currency'=>'PHP'
);
    $data = array(
        'invoice_date'=>'2020-05-01',
        'items'=>array($items),
    );

echo post($data, $url, $headers);


function post($data,$url,$headers)
    {
        $payload = json_encode($data);
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
    }

?>
```

C:\Users\ronvi\Projects\PHP> php index.php

The error returned upon posting via PHP curl

```
* About to connect() to (my website) port 443 (#0)
*   Trying (my web server IP address)...
* connected
* Connected to (my domain name) (my web server IP address) port 443 (#0)
* error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
* Closing connection #0
```

Your suggestions or ideas are really appreciated thank you.

Thank you,

Ron

Comment: Both PHP 5.4.9 and OpenSSL 0.9.8x are WAY out of date. As is Windows 7. You need to upgrade. The more time you invest trying to go around this fact is just lost time. Also, as is, your question is not fully on topic, as you do not even show your PHP code, so noone knows how you handle the TLS handshake, what libraries you use, etc...

Comment: ^^ What Patrick said. Your entire technology stack on the local machine is out of date and unsupported. It's way past being time to upgrade all of it. Why do you want to avoid doing that?

Comment: Patrick Mevzek and Adyson. The client or owner of the server does not allow me to upgrade their current operating system or even install another application.

Comment: I don't have permission to do upgrade on the local server setup but i do have on the remote server which is our web server.

Comment: I just need to post the data from local to our remote server and that's it.

Comment: Patrick Mevzek, please refresh your page, added my code to my question. Thank you!

Comment: Your client's infra is _horrifyingly_ out of date. I can't think of a way to accommodate them without crippling the security of your own infra. This is the point where you talk to your boss and present a united front to the customer and say "we cannot accommodate you unless you upgrade".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using **curl for windows** as the data sender with https/http instead.

I downloaded the binary from the official website https://curl.haxx.se/windows/, extracted it somewhere in the local machine and add the binary directory to the Environment variable, and updated the PHP code, see below.

```
<?php

$items = array(
    'customer_no'=>'001',
    'customer_name'=>'John Smith',
    'customer_address'=>'Bohol Philippines',
    'customer_province'=>'Bohol',
    'customer_city'=>'Tagbilaran',
    'salesman_no'=>'001',
    'salesman_name'=>'Salesman A',
    'salesman_mobile_no'=>'0912345678',
    'supervisor_id'=>'001',
    'supervisor_name'=>'Supervisor A',
    'item_no'=>'001',
    'item_description'=>'Detergent',
    'qty'=>2,
    'price'=>5,
    'uom'=>'pcs',
    'sales_value'=>'10',
    'currency'=>'PHP'
);
    $data = array(
        'invoice_date'=>'2020-05-01',
        'items'=>array($items),
    );

$json = json_encode($data);
$json = str_replace('"', '\"', $json); // using ' to wrap json data is not working in windows
$curl = "curl -X POST -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" -H \"AUTH-TOKEN: ******\" https://****.com.ph/api/daily/sales --data \"".$json."\" "; // CURL command
exec($curl,$response); // execute CURL command
print_r($response); // print array response

?>
```

It's surprising that CURL version 7.70.0 is perfectly working on an old operating system like Windows 7, 32-bit architecture.